# How to assign multiple values to an array of strings in python

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop

I'm reading a file line by line and am trying to parse a part of each line and do stuff with it. the Info that I'm trying to parse are 25 strings

I was trying to do

```
for i in info:
  Consequence=i[0]    
  IMPACT=i[1]
  .
  .
  HGNC_ID = i[24]
```

but obviously there's a better way of doing this. I tried making a list of all the strings and initialize them as empty strings, and then did:

```
                  for counter,val in enumerate(info_list):

                    try:
                        val=i[counter]
                        break
                    except:
                        val=""
```

where

```
info_list=(Allele,Consequence...)
```

That doesn't work though, it prints empty strings and counter is always zero, even though the length of info_list is 25.

What would be the best way to assign those values? (keep in mind that some "infos" might have 23 or 24 values in the array, in that case I would want to assign an empty string to the missing values, the missing values would only be at the end so there is no confusion as to which variables are missing)

Let me know if I can add more information!

Thanks! :)

Comment: If you are reading from a file, and it looks like a CSV format, you will save yourself a lot of trouble by using a `DictReader`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There does not seem to be much wrong with your first version of the code. I don't know why you think there "obviously" should be a better way.

One thing you can do to make this a little clearer is:

```
if len(info) == 25:
    Consequence, IMPACT , . . ., HGNC_ID  = info
elif len(info) == 24:
    Consequence , IMPACT , . . ., HGNC_ID = info + ''
```

But I doubt if that will make it much better.

What you might want to consider is not using variables but a hash table or a named tuple for the values you read from the line.